# Create a dropdown menu with arrow pointer in SASS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, compass-sass, compass

I want to know how can I implement dropdown menu with arrow pointer in CSS (SASS).
The idea is simple:

1) menu dropdown on press on left or right button

2) dropdown always centred and takes 85% of screen width (please refer screenshot http://joxi.ru/12MpgxpI4y8olm).

3) only the arrow should point 1 or 2 when clicking the respective button.

Here is where problems came:

1) I use absolutely positioned dropdown window (and the arrow too therefore) and all his parents up to the action button itself have position: static (this is required to have a dropdown window always aligned to the left side of a screen and take a % of screen's width)

2) Arrow starts to be positioned against screen size - instead of being positioned against her grandparent - action button. Arrow starts posing against button only if I remove position: static from button, but in this case I've lost dropdown taking full-screen with and aligned to left corder of a screen (it starts to show up against button).

I've tried to do some implementation with flexbox / clearfix, but it seems doesn't work with static elements. Or I misunderstood the idea.

So, my questions are:

1) How I can build a dropdown with arrow pointer properly as I described above and showed on a screenshot? (http://joxi.ru/12MpgxpI4y8olm)
Any ideas?

2) How in CSS (SASS/SCSS) I can get grandparent's position (left, margin-left, padding-left - something like that)? Grandparent == parent of parent :)

I need to support only modern browsers, so e.g. IE before version 9 doesn't really matters to me.

Current styles look like this:

```
.listing-action-button
  position: static
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: flex-start

  .dropdown-menu
    left: 5% !important
    margin-top: 1.5%
    width: 80% !important
    float: left !important
    position: absolute !important

    &:before
      flex-grow: 1
      align-self: flex-start

      position: absolute
      top: -7px
      left: 9px
      display: inline-block
      border-right: 7px solid transparent
      border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc
      border-left: 7px solid transparent
      border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
      content: ''
    &:after
      position: absolute
      top: -6px
      left: 10px
      display: inline-block
    border-right: 6px solid transparent
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff
    border-left: 6px solid transparent
    content: ''
```

It's based on standard bootstrap's dropdown-menu.
flex-* stuff isn't working, you can omit it.

HAML code for buttons group and dropdown:

<...>

```
  .col-sm-6.col-xs-12.col-sm-pull-3
    .user-listing__main{ style: "margin-top: -12px;" }
      .user-listing__buttons.user-listing__buttons-tablet.btn-group.btn-group-justified
        .btn-group.listing-action-button.left-button{:role => "group"}
          %button.btn.btn-lg.btn-default.dropdown-toggle{ type: "button",  :style => "width: 100%;", data: { toggle: "dropdown" }  }
            Preview
            %span.caret
          %ul.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-no-border{ role: "menu" }
            .menu-arrow
            %li{ class: ("disabled" if disable_edit) }
              %a#user-listings__make-featured{ href: edit_listing_path(token: listing.token), role: "group", type: "button", style: "width: 100%;" }
                %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
                = t 'user.listings.edit'
            %li
              %a#user-listings__launch-facebook-campaign{ href: listing_preview_path(token: listing.token), role: 'button', target: '_blank', type: 'button', style: "width: 100%;" }
                %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-eye-open
                = t 'user.listings.preview'

        .btn-group.listing-action-button.right-button{:role => "group"}
          %button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-inverted.dropdown-toggle{ type: "button",  :style => "width: 100%;", data: { toggle: "dropdown" }  }
            Promote
            %span.caret
          %ul.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-no-border{ role: "menu" }
            .menu-arrow
            %li.mark-featured{ data: {"listing-id" => listing.id} }
              %a#user-listings__make-featured{ href: "#" }
                %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star{ class: ("active" if is_featured?(listing)) }
                = t 'user.listings.make_featured'
            %li.disabled
              %a#user-listings__launch-facebook-campaign{ href: "#" }
                %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-thumbs-up
                Launch Facebook Campaign
```

<...>